# let user disable certain array items?

Tags: php, arrays

This is the situation, I've got a big array ( 280 items ) which creates a really big form by going trough loops.

I want the user to be able to disable certain items, so they can 'pre make' their form ( and skip the not used ones ), You are probably going to say i can just remove what's not needed. But they need different items from the array every time they use it.

So how would i make a page where they can just use checkbox to 'change' the form. ( if possible at all.)

Thanks,
Mike

edit: 
Did not think of sharing code, here:
The array : http://pastebin.com/EnwHsqtK

the form : http://pastebin.com/y2XSFBG4

the page which makes a .txt file from the given answers. http://pastebin.com/UaUcsj2z ( not sure if anyone would need this. )

Might be a bit messy. I'm new in PHP, and only programming for a year. Also dont mind the language please.

Comment: Care to post some test code?

Comment: Also try to use jQuery with an event handler that uses `.hide()` or `.show()` to show certain elements by ID

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanently record form preferences/settings for each user, you'd want to create an additional table or column(s) in your database for this, give the users additional checkboxes on the form to indicate their preferences, receive this input and store it in the database, and of course finally disable certain fields based on their settings.

But if you just want to give the users a temporary way to disable certain fields (with no preferences saved permanently), you would use JavaScript in your output.  You would add more form controls (checkboxes or buttons or whatever) to the HTML and then add JavaScript code snippets into that HTML to disable form elements when the user clicked on the controls.  This kind of making changes when users click is called "triggers that fire based on events".  The most commonly-used event is called "OnClick()" and the JavaScript code for it will execute when a user clicks on something.

Many folks who use JavaScript also find it helpful to use the functions in the jQuery library instead of raw JavaScript.  To do this, you just add one line of HTML to the top of your page to include the JavaScript libraries from a publicly-hosted server, then you can use jQuery commands in your page.

The only thing to remember when you first start using JavaScript/jQuery is that it only runs on the client browser - its code cannot talk directly to the server, the database, or many things you can access in PHP.  JavaScript/jQuery is specifically used for making your HTML pages more interactive.  Plain HTML doesn't have much razzle-dazzle.  JavaScript allows users to do things like enable and disable form fields on-the-fly.